Copy and Paste files in a Razor Project in Visual Studio Solution Explorer
I want to be able to Copy and Paste my .razor files and then rename them instead of adding a .razor component through the menus.
At times I am able to Copy and Paste files and the IDE creates a Copy directly in the Project Explorer.  Other times the IDE does nothing.
Is this a Bug in Visual Studio?
Thank you.


"Is this a bug in Visual Studio?" Yes, this is likely a bug in Visual Studio. I've experienced it and other users have as well since upgrading to 17.11. Follow this issue at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Copy-and-Paste-Files-or-Folders-Failed-:/10711246

As Dave mentioned in the comments this is currently a Bug and is being discussed at:
Copy and Paste Error
